# How to read a specific unique json attribute in jackson

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

This is a json of an api. my query only asks for one language (here "en") so there is only one value in the json. And this is the only thing i want to read in the json. So i think i doesnt make sense to convert it to an object. I thought of something like:

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(genreJson); ...
```

But how do i get the value without knowing the name of the attribute (in the example "12345"). This is an Id i dont have.
What do you think?

```
{
    "entities":
    {
        "12345":
        {
            "id": "12345",
            "type": "item",
            "descriptions":
            {
                "en":
                {
                    "language": "en",
                    "value": "the_value_i_want"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "success": 1
}
```

i thought something like

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(genreJson); ...
```

Comment: @victorkohl ==> i edited the question to match the requirements. whats the next step?

Answer (score 0):

try this.. may work

```
 JsonNode value = root.path("entities").path("12345").path("descriptions").path("en").path("value");
```

I am not sure if its an efficient approach though

Comment: value is null. Maybe because its not a direct child below root?

Comment: i dont know why the api uses an id as attribute name, but it does (why do you do something like that? Do you know?) The point is i dont have the id here e.g. "12345".

Comment: Hmm.. I am not sure what's happening there? I just followed the path to get you the value of attribute "value". It's weird that it is using the value of id as an attribute name, are you sure it is happening with the other nodes in the JSON ?

Comment: to clear it up i meant the json api not the jackson api. the problem is that i dont have the id so i cant access like you suggested with .path("12345")